Meaning of “想要” as opposed to “想” and “要”
I have seen the words “要”，“想”，and “想要” all being used in similar contexts and I understand that they all mean 'to want/need' something. If I understood correctly, “要” is more frequently used for needing something while “想” can be translated to 'would like'. I am slightly confused on how “想要” is related to both terms and in what situations this can/can't be used as opposed to the other terms.

There's two related questions: What does 想要 emphasize exactly? and How do I understand the meaning of 想 and 想要?.  (My answer to this question is here.)

[想 + v] means [want to + v]
[要 + v] can mean either [want to + v], [demand to] or [need to + v]
[想要 + v] means [want to + v] or [attempt to + v]

When you want to say "need to" you can only choose "要" among the three

When you want to say "want to", you can use "要", "想要" or "想"; Using "想" makes it unambiguous because it doesn't contain other meanings

When you want to say "attempt to" you can only pick "想要" among the three


Note: With a clear context, you can deduct 要 means "want to" or "need to" in most cases
Examples:
我要去美國 = I want to/need to go to America
我要去美國度假 = I want/demand to go to America for a vacation (going on a vacation is something you want to do in most cases)
我要去美國公幹 = I need to go to America for a business trip (going on a business trip is something you need to do in most cases)

Thanks so much, I understand now.

What is the difference between want and desire?
想和要表达意愿时的主要差别在于语气的强弱和行动的可能性。
The main difference between xiǎng hé yào, when they express desire, lies in the strength of tone (of expression) and the probability of the desired outcome.
语气强弱：
Strong or weak tone:
“想”的语气稍弱，表示有这个计划或想法，但不一定必须完成。
The tone of "xiǎng" is somewhat weak,
表示有这个计划或想法，
(it) expresses (one) has a plan or notion,
但不一定必须完成。
but (that plan) must not necessarily come to fruition.
“要”的语气更强，
(Whereas) the tone of " yào" (is) comparatively strong
表示强烈的愿望或决心，
(it) expresses strong aspiration or determination,
计划或打算一定要完成。
(the) plan or intention definitely must come to fruition.
行动的可能性：
(The) probability (of the) activity (happening):
使用“想”时，
When (you) use "xiǎng"
行动的可能性较为不确定，
(the) probablility of (the) activity is uncertain,
可能做也可能不做。
(you) may do it or (you) may not do it.
使用“要”时，
When you use " yào"
通常表示说话人最终会按照意愿去行动。
(this) normally expresses (that) the speaker ultimately will act according to his or her aspiration.
此外，
Apart from that,
两者在用法和表达否定方面也存在差异：
both (words) in (normal) use and negation also have differences:
用法：
Use
“想”多用于向别人提出请求，
"xiǎng" (is) often used to raise a polite request,
显得比较客气、礼貌。
("xiǎng") appears relatively polite and courteous.
“要”在某些情境下可能显得较为强势或随便。
" yào" in any situation appears strong and wilful.
表达否定：
Expressing negation
“不想”通常表示没有某种想法或打算。
"bùxiǎng" mostly expresses lack of any kind of desire or intention.
“不要”则一般用来劝阻别人或禁止做某件事。
"bùyào" on the other hand (is) generally used to dissuade or forbid other people from doing something.
总的来说，
In summary,
“想”和“要”在表达个人意愿时，
" xiǎng hé yào" when used to express an individual's desire,
虽然都表示愿望或打算，
although both express desire or intention,
但“想”更侧重于表达一种可能性的想法，
however "xiǎng" puts more emphasis on expressing a kind of likelihood of the notion,
而“要”则更强调决心和行动的可能性。
and " yào" puts more emphasis on the (strong) probability of determination and activity (in the matter).
"要" 和 "想要" 的差别 就是语气上的差别。
The difference between " yào" and "xiǎngyào" is a (also) difference of tone.
‘要’用在句中表示祈使，
" yào" (when) used in a sentence is imperative,
语气肯定些，坚决些。
the tone is more definite, more resolute.
‘想要’用在句中表示得比较委婉，表达的是一种愿望。
"xiǎngyào" (when) used in a sentence is more tactful, the expression is a kind of wish (or hope).

I see, thank you!

The example sentences below may help to clear up the question on the occasion to use each word:

我想做一個老师 - I want/intend to be a teacher. (wish/desired to be)

我要做一個老师 - I want/must to be a teacher. (firm/strong desire)

我想要做一個老师 - I wish to be a teacher. (modest wish/desired to be)




Thanks for the examples, they are really useful!

You are welcome. Wish you realize that the words "想", "要", and "想要", while all express a desire for something, the mindsets/tunes are quite different - "想" is more of a wishful thought; "要" is an absolute/definite demand; "想要" is a declaration of intention.
